# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) on where method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)` error on a where call.

Wondering if it's got something to do with associations, but not sure.

```
> Member.where(skill_primary: 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):8
SystemStackError (stack level too deep)
```

Here's what a singular Member object looks like:

```
#<Member 
  id: 500, 
  name: "Godiva Headache", 
  gender: "", 
  birthdate: "1958-04-12", 
  cost: 0, 
  trait_stamina: 0, 
  trait_ego: 15, 
  trait_looks: 2, 
  trait_drive: 0, 
  trait_productivity: 0, 
  trait_aptitude: 0, 
  trait_creativity: 54, 
  trait_network: 0, 
  trait_fatigue: 0, 
  skill_primary: 8, 
  skill_primary_level: 53, 
  skill_secondary: nil, 
  skill_secondary_level: 0, 
  skill_tertiary: nil, 
  skill_tertiary_level: 0, 
  created_at: "2018-04-12 14:36:46", 
  updated_at: "2018-04-12 14:36:46"
>
```

Member model:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill_primary, class_name: 'Skill', foreign_key: :skill_primary
end
```

Skill model:

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :member_skills
  has_many :members, through: :member_skills
end
```

Running Rails 5.2 on Postgres.

Comment: I bet it has to do with the name of your `belongs_to` association and the name of the `foreign_key`. Is there a reason why you named your foreign key as `skill_primary` ?, why didn't you use `skill_prymary_id`(or grammatically better `primary_skill_id`) ?. Do a quick test by changing your `belongs_to :skill_primary` to `belongs_to :primary_skill` and leave the foreign key as it is.

Comment: @fanta Ah your quick test did the trick. Thanks!